# jquery mobile header - using image as page link

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, header

I am attempting to basically use a shopping cart image in my header as a link to another page (order page) that contains a list of the items added to the user's cart.

I had everything working perfectly, only the image was not a link to the orders page.

Here is what I had:

```
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <img src="img/cartEmpty.png" class="ui-btn-right" id="cart_logo">
    <label id="items_in_cart" class="ui-btn-right"></label>
  </div>
```

This is a snippet of my CSS that was sizing the cart image to fill the header's height:

```
#cart_logo {
    height:90%;
    width:auto;
}
```

And here is what I currently have, which is making the image way too big. I just want the cart image to be scaled so that it stays contained in the header and is also a link to the orders page:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <a href="#order" class="ui-btn-right"><img src="img/cartEmpty.png" id="cart_logo"></a>
    <label id="items_in_cart" class="ui-btn-right"></label>
</div>
```

For a better idea of what I am trying to do, see Amazon's cart image.

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.5

Comment: I need to inspect your page to see why its not working but i suspect the image needs to be a background image on the button. however, you gave the image an id="cart_logo" so you can create a click event to go to the order page eg ($(document).on("click", "#cart_logo", function(event) { $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#order", { transition: "the-transition-you-want" }); }))